# Key Vault secret values are displayed as plain text in Bash script

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-keyvault

AzureKeyVault@1 task retrieves all the secrets, some of the secrets are displayed as *** whereas some newly created ones are shown as plain text.
A part of my pipeline:

```
     steps:
        -   task: AzureKeyVault@1
            displayName: Download secrets from KeyVault
            inputs:
                azureSubscription: azure_sub
                KeyVaultName: key_vault
                SecretsFilter: '*'
                RunAsPreJob: true

        -   task: PipAuthenticate@1
            displayName: Authentication step
            inputs:
                artifactFeeds: organization
                onlyAddExtraIndex: true 

        -   script: |
                echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=keyvault_variable;isOutput=true]$(keyvault_variable)"
            displayName: Set environment variables
            name: SetVariables

-   stage: Stage2
    jobs:
    -   job: check_if_encrypted
        steps:
        -   task: CmdLine@2
            displayName: Write secrets
            inputs:
                script: |
                    echo keyvault_variable
```

Is there any changes to the Azure Key Vault or wrong with the pipeline?
Thanks

Comment: Ok, the idea is not to print the plain text, somehow i have it as plain text printed :(

Answer (score 1):

You're creating an unencrypted copy of the secret value with `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=keyvault_variable;isOutput=true]$(keyvault_variable)"`. You should specify `isSecret=true` if you want it to continue to be a secret.

Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: But how is it that, it is creating an unencrpyted copy of some variables and not the others? Thats whats puzzling me

Comment: @Antulii All I can go by is what you posted. What you posted shows a single secret value being explicitly re-copied to an unencrypted variable. If you can show examples of other scenarios that result in unencrypted secrets, I'm sure it can be explained.

Answer (score -1):

It seems we have to explicitly mention : `issecret=true` in the

`echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=keyvault_variable;isOutput=true]$(keyvault_variable)"` script. Only then it masks.

What is not clear is why this has to be set for certain for certain sercrets whereas for others it worked without explicitly mentioning.